# how to do scroll in scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

My scroll view is containing 4 views. Below are the first three in my scroll view
[image]

**My goal** : i would like to scroll so that my scroll view will show the second + the third + the fourth view ( the first view will be off )

**Question** : how can i do that

Right now when i scroll, i am getting

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of things, it seems as though you aren't adding the other views, or you're not adding them in the proper position.

In order to have a UIScrollView work, you'll need to set the `contentSize` and `frame` properties and position the subviews as if it were one big map. Say you had three 200x200 views you wanted to add, you would set their individual frame properties to (0, 0, 200, 200), (200, 0, 200, 200), (400, 0, 200, 200), if you wanted them side by side. Then you would need the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` property set to (600, 200) in order to have it scroll through all of it.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: i did add 4 views into my scrollview. the coordinations of my views are  (0, 0, 100, 50), (100, 0, 100, 50), (200, 0, 100, 50), (300, 0, 100, 50). However, when I set the contentSize, i do ( 600, 100 ). Therefore, I am getting extra white space behind. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Oh. So you were just making the contentSize property too large, right?

Comment: sorry still not working. now i have 0 1 2 3 4 5 in my scrollview. Firstly, 0 and 1 and 2 are visible and 1 is a in a center of scroll view.( 3 and 4 and 5 are not shown yet) Next I want to show 1 and 2 and 3 and 2 is in center ( 0 is just off and 4 and 5 is still off ). However, when I scroll, it shows 3 and 4 and 5.......

Comment: Are you trying to have the scroll view page between views?

Comment: @ttran Cool! Let me know if you have any other issues. Maybe I can help.